# When fargate container is reloaded? after ecs repository is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I made `ecs` `fargate` with container.

My procedure is like this

`codecommit` -> `codepipeline`(`codebuild`) -> `ecs repository`.

`fargate` uses the `ecs repository`

When I push code to `codecommit`, `codepipeline` works and `ecs repository` is updated.

However container in `fargate` is not updated.

I stop the tasks manually, the tasks restart, but container itself is not updated.

What should I do for this?

I need to make codepipelline(again???) ecs repository to fargate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update a task definition so your container can start using the updated image.
And then you need to stop old task and start new task.
Or, if this is an ECS Service, you need to update the service to use the updated task definition.

Comment: I stopped the task manually, it restart the new version. thank you very much.